# How do I add a copyright symbol to a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to add a copyright symbol in part of a `UITableView` footer.  How do I place this symbol within a string in my application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copyright \u00A9 2010"]
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/07/objective-c-tuesdays-unicode-string.html

Same approach as any other framework/programming language that doesn't have UTF source files.